# Find happy ducks sql puzzle

Tags: sql, postgresql

Adapted from here: http://sridhargaddam28.blogspot.com/2017/03/sql-puzzle.html

**Setup**

Each duck belongs to a particular species and lives in one of the several ponds. Each pond is described by its temperature and location city. Each species is described by two values: its thermal preferences and its temperature limit. Depending on their thermal preferences, duck from a given species may prefer temperatures not higher or not lower than the temperature limit. A duck of a certain species will only feel comfortable if the temperature in the pond fulfills its thermal preferences(i.e. it is above/below or equal to the species' limit temperature).

The column temp_preferences in table species determines whether temp_limit is minimum ("+") or maximum ("-") acceptable temperature for the given species. Rows in all tables are ordered by the column id.
For each pond we would like to count the ducks which live in it and feel comfortable.

You are giving 3 tables: species, ponds and ducks

**Question**

Write an SQL query that returns a table consisting of 2 columns: pond_id, happy_ducks, ordered by pond_id. **Every pond should appear in this table.**

**Setup Code for SQLFiddle (sqlfiddle.com)**

```
create table species(
id integer not null,
temp_preferences varchar(1) check(temp_preferences in('+', '-')),
temp_limit integer not null,
  unique(id)
);

create table ponds (
id integer not null,
temperature integer not null,
city varchar(10),
unique(id)
);

create table ducks (
id integer not null,
name varchar(10),
species_id integer not null,
pond_id integer not null,
unique(id)
);

INSERT Into species VALUES (30, '+', 15);
INSERT Into species VALUES (40, '-', 20);
INSERT Into species VALUES (50, '-', 31);

INSERT Into ponds VALUES (1, 13, 'Oregon');
INSERT Into ponds VALUES (2, 31, 'Oregano');
INSERT Into ponds VALUES (3, 25, 'Test Lake');


INSERT Into ducks VALUES (1, 'Martin', 50,2 );
INSERT Into ducks VALUES (3, 'Bruno', 30,1 );
INSERT Into ducks VALUES (9, 'Ignacio', 40,2 );
INSERT Into ducks VALUES (27, 'Hedwig', 40,1 );
INSERT Into ducks VALUES (81, 'Marina', 30,2 );
```

**My Answer & Problem**

I have the following but it doesnt return the empty pond (pond 3). Can anyone help me out?

```
SELECT p.id, COUNT(d.id) as happy_ducks FROM ducks d
FULL OUTER JOIN ponds p on d.pond_id=p.id
FULL OUTER JOIN species s ON d.species_id=s.id
WHERE
(p.temperature <= s.temp_limit and s.temp_preferences='+') OR
(p.temperature >= s.temp_limit and s.temp_preferences='-')
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: Hint:  Rows from the `JOIN` that do not meet the `WHERE` conditions are removed from the result set and therefore do not take part in the `GROUP BY` aggregation.  Consider using a `FILTER` on the `COUNT()` aggregation, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filtering by comparing pond and species temperature. If there is no duck, there is no species and the query is comparing the pond temperature to a NULL species temperature, which fails.

To get the empty pond, you need to explicitly consider this case in the where clause, by adding `OR s.id IS NULL`

Comment: Doh such a simple fix! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
SELECT p.id, COUNT(d.id) as happy_ducks
FROM ponds p
LEFT JOIN ducks d on d.pond_id=p.id
LEFT JOIN species s ON d.species_id=s.id and ((p.temperature <= s.temp_limit and s.temp_preferences='+') OR
(p.temperature >= s.temp_limit and s.temp_preferences='-'))
GROUP BY p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

I will do this in multiple steps the reason is two fold.

1. With this approach, every step of the SQL execution can be taken out and a temp table or CTE can be created.
2. Convenient to test each piece individually and optimize.

**Step 1**: Get the data regarding the pond and ducks with ponds which has no ducks as well , hence PONDS will need to be OUTER table in the OUTER join. DUCKS will be the inner table as it will have NULLS for for ponds that does not have ducks.
It is necessary to preserve this condition in the original question:
“
Every pond should appear in this table.
“

```
SELECT p.id          pond_id,
                                       p.temperature tempx,
                                       d.id          duck_id,
                                       d.species_id  sp_id
                                FROM   ponds p
                                       LEFT OUTER JOIN ducks d
                                                    ON p.id = d.pond_id;

 pond_id | tempx | duck_id | sp_id
---------+-------+---------+-------
       2 |    31 |       1 |    50
       1 |    13 |       3 |    30
       2 |    31 |       9 |    40
       1 |    13 |      27 |    40
       2 |    31 |      81 |    30
       3 |    25 |         |       -----> This pond (id =3) does not have ducks on it.
```

**Step 2**:  Join the result from step 1 which has Duck and Ponds data to Species of Ducks that each Duck belong to. The Step 1 data will be the dataset which will again be OUTER joined with Species to preserve the PONDS with no ducks as mentioned in Step 1.

```
SELECT dp.pond_id,
                               dp.tempx,
                               dp.duck_id,
                               s.temp_limit,
                               s.temp_preferences
                        FROM   (SELECT p.id          pond_id,
                                       p.temperature tempx,
                                       d.id          duck_id,
                                       d.species_id  sp_id
                                FROM   ponds p
                                       LEFT OUTER JOIN ducks d
                                                    ON p.id = d.pond_id) dp
                               LEFT OUTER JOIN species s
                                            ON dp.sp_id = s.id

pond_id | tempx | duck_id | temp_limit | temp_preferences
---------+-------+---------+------------+------------------
       2 |    31 |       1 |         31 | -
       1 |    13 |       3 |         15 | +
       2 |    31 |       9 |         20 | -
       1 |    13 |      27 |         20 | -
       2 |    31 |      81 |         15 | +
       3 |    25 |         |            |
(6 rows)
```

**Step 3**: Now we need to find out  the mood of the Duck from what ever was obtained in Step 2.  The ducks are happy if the temperature of the pond (tempx) is more or less based on its speci temperature limit preference (+/-) respectively.
In addition ,if there is no ducks , it has to be factored in as well.

All this is implemented through the CASE statement:

If  there is no temperature limit for any duck or speci — pond does not have duck.

If temperature preference is + and the current temperature of the pond (tempx) is more than the temperature limit for the speci of the ducks in it — duck is happy.

If temperature preference is - and the current temperature of the pond (tempx) is less than the temperature limit  for the speci of the ducks in it  — duck is happy.

In all other cases , the ducks in the pond are ‘sad’.

```
SELECT pond_id,
                       COALESCE(duck_id, -1) duckid,
                       CASE
                         WHEN temp_limit IS NULL THEN 'no'
                         WHEN tempx >= temp_limit
                              AND temp_preferences = '+' THEN 'happy'
                         WHEN tempx <= temp_limit
                              AND temp_preferences = '-' THEN 'happy'
                         ELSE 'sad'
                       END                   mood
                FROM   (SELECT dp.pond_id,
                               dp.tempx,
                               dp.duck_id,
                               s.temp_limit,
                               s.temp_preferences
                        FROM   (SELECT p.id          pond_id,
                                       p.temperature tempx,
                                       d.id          duck_id,
                                       d.species_id  sp_id
                                FROM   ponds p
                                       LEFT OUTER JOIN ducks d
                                                    ON p.id = d.pond_id) dp
                               LEFT OUTER JOIN species s
                                            ON dp.sp_id = s.id) x;

pond_id | duckid | mood
---------+--------+-------
       2 |      1 | happy
       1 |      3 | sad
       2 |      9 | sad
       1 |     27 | happy
       2 |     81 | happy
       3 |     -1 | no
```

**Step 4**: Assign a score of 1 if a duck is happy in the pond and a score of 0 if there is no duck in the pond or the duck is sad.

```
SELECT pond_id,
               CASE
                 WHEN mood = 'happy' THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
               END re_mood
        FROM   (SELECT pond_id,
                       COALESCE(duck_id, -1) duckid,
                       CASE
                         WHEN temp_limit IS NULL THEN 'no'
                         WHEN tempx >= temp_limit
                              AND temp_preferences = '+' THEN 'happy'
                         WHEN tempx <= temp_limit
                              AND temp_preferences = '-' THEN 'happy'
                         ELSE 'sad'
                       END                   mood
                FROM   (SELECT dp.pond_id,
                               dp.tempx,
                               dp.duck_id,
                               s.temp_limit,
                               s.temp_preferences
                        FROM   (SELECT p.id          pond_id,
                                       p.temperature tempx,
                                       d.id          duck_id,
                                       d.species_id  sp_id
                                FROM   ponds p
                                       LEFT OUTER JOIN ducks d
                                                    ON p.id = d.pond_id) dp
                               LEFT OUTER JOIN species s
                                            ON dp.sp_id = s.id) x) y;
   
pond_id | re_mood
---------+---------
       2 |       1
       1 |       0
       2 |       0
       1 |       1
       2 |       1
       3 |       0
```

**Step 5**: Find the sum of values ducks with "Happy" for each POND.

```
SELECT pond_id,
       Sum(re_mood) happy_ducks
FROM   (SELECT pond_id,
               CASE
                 WHEN mood = 'happy' THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
               END re_mood
        FROM   (SELECT pond_id,
                       COALESCE(duck_id, -1) duckid,
                       CASE
                         WHEN temp_limit IS NULL THEN 'no'
                         WHEN tempx >= temp_limit
                              AND temp_preferences = '+' THEN 'happy'
                         WHEN tempx <= temp_limit
                              AND temp_preferences = '-' THEN 'happy'
                         ELSE 'sad'
                       END                   mood
                FROM   (SELECT dp.pond_id,
                               dp.tempx,
                               dp.duck_id,
                               s.temp_limit,
                               s.temp_preferences
                        FROM   (SELECT p.id          pond_id,
                                       p.temperature tempx,
                                       d.id          duck_id,
                                       d.species_id  sp_id
                                FROM   ponds p
                                       LEFT OUTER JOIN ducks d
                                                    ON p.id = d.pond_id) dp
                               LEFT OUTER JOIN species s
                                            ON dp.sp_id = s.id) x) y) z
GROUP  BY pond_id order by pond_id;

pond_id | happy_ducks
---------+-------------
       1 |           1
       2 |           2
       3 |           0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it to get the empty pond

```
SELECT D.pond_id, SUM(D.is_happy)
FROM
(SELECT ponds.id,
 CASE
     WHEN (ponds.temperature >= species.temp_limit and species.temp_preferences
     = '+') or (ponds.temperature <= species.temp_limit and 
     species.temp_preferences = '-') THEN 1
     ELSE 0
  END AS is_happy
  FROM ducks
  full outer join ponds on ducks.pond_id = ponds.id
  full outer join species on ducks.species_id = species.id) as D
  
GROUP BY D.pond_id
ORDER BY D.pond_id
```